# How to export an html file with a foldable & dynamic TOC from an org file?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, css

When HTML pages are extended I find it quite useful to have a TOC (table of Content) available all along with your scrolling.

A good example of an implementation of such a functionality is the Worg webpages ([here is an example](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html)), which are generated from org files.

So my question is, how is this done? Is it done through a CSS file? If it is, what would the CSS code be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line has to be put on top of your org file:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg.css"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's done with a Javascript library called `org-info.js`, written by Sebastian Rose. See the [Javascript support](https://orgmode.org/manual/JavaScript-support.html#JavaScript-support) section of the Org mode manual. There is also some additional documentation in [Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/code/org-info-js/).

Comment: Hi NickD, are you sure org-info.js handles dynamic TOC?  My goal is not to have an Info-like, nor a folding view

Comment: Ok, it actually was done through a CSS: https://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg.css

Comment: Oh, I probably conflated the two. Sorry about that.